# Time to Event data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
id Date Observation
1  2    A
1  3    B
1  8    C
2  11   C
2  3    B
2  7    A
3  9    A
3  10   A
3  5    B
```

I would like to organize the data into having multiple columns for each observation, the date to be chronologically ordered and each observation to get 0 before it appeared, 1 when it first appeared, and 1 afterward. In the end, it should look something like this:

```
id Date A B C
1  2    1 0 0
1  3    1 1 0
1  8    1 1 1
2  3    0 1 0
2  7    1 1 0
2  11   1 1 1
3  5    0 1 0
3  9    1 1 0
3  10   1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape the data to wide format and for each `id` turn all the value to 1 once it occurs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Observation, values_from = Observation, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
  arrange(id, Date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(A:C, cummax)) %>%
  ungroup

#    id   Date     A     B     C
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1     0     0
#2     1     3     1     1     0
#3     1     8     1     1     1
#4     2     3     0     1     0
#5     2     7     1     1     0
#6     2    11     1     1     1
#7     3     5     0     1     0
#8     3     9     1     1     0
#9     3    10     1     1     0
```